# Laravel conditional on relation: return first()

Tags: laravel

I have a `Laravel 5.2` `one-to-many relation` and I want to return the model and put a condition to relation.
I've tried this:

```
$categories = Category::with(['descriptions' => function($d) use ($default_language) {
    $d->where('language_id', $default_language->id);
}])->get();
```

It work fine, I just want something else: the relation should not be a collection or array, just a simple object. I want to do something like

```
$d->where('language_id', $default_language->id)->first();
```

, just in this case `first()` is not working. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Actually `first()` is not working properly, it returns first description just for the first object returned, for others it return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categories = \Jobinja\CMS\Blog\Models\Category::with([
        'descriptions' => function ($q) use ($defaultLanguage) {
            return $q->where('language_id', $defaultLanguage->id)->take(1);
        }
    ])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) {
            if ($item->descriptions->isEmpty() === false) {
                $item->description = $item->descriptions->first();
            }

            return $item;
    });
```

and get to description:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $description = $category->description;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, very interesting, only just a minor change: it returns both one descriptions and descriptions. Can I get rid of descriptions?

Comment: you can unset or empty `descriptions` attribute of each item in map closure before `return $item`

Comment: Sounds like an workaround, but it's cool, work perfectly! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but you can use `first()` on a collection later, for example in a view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->descriptions->first()->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok, good enought, honestly didn't I can do that. But for me it works with ->descriptions()->first(); The problem is that this return in an API, which I use later, so it will still be confusing for others that is returning an array...

Answer (score 0):

I can say to use instead of `first()` `find()` and give it the `language_id` or `$default_language->id` and this will try to find in the table first the column `id` and assign the value. If you have different id column name give it to the find like `find(['your_column_name' => '<your_value'])`.

If you want array to something like ->toArray(). You can test different scenarios in tinker. `php artisan tinker`

Here is a link to document this -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models